# Why can not change UITabBar badge font iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, badge

I try to change **UITabBar badge** font like this:

```
cartTab = tabBar.items![2]
let font =  UIFont(name: "MyFontName", size: 11)!
cartTab?.setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: font], for: .normal)
cartTab?.setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: font], for: .selected).
```

I set this code in my custom tabbar controller (**viewDidLoad**).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `AppDelegate` (**Swift 3**)

```
let font =  UIFont(name: "MyFontName", size: 11)!
UITabBarItem.appearance().setBadgeTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setBadgeTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], for: .selected)
```

---

**Update:**

**Swift4**

```
let font =  UIFont(name: "MyFontName", size: 11)!
UITabBarItem.appearance().setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .selected)
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedStringKey' to expected dictionary key type 'String'         have to change to NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue

Comment: check edit please

Comment: Unfortunately not work on iOS 12.

Comment: I have checked and that works, make sure about your font Target Membership and xcode knows your font

Comment: Same, this code does no effect on iOS 12-13